# GameWindow crash at launch

Tags: c#, sdl-2, opentk

I got a problem using `GameWindow` class of `opentk`,
later I was able to launch a simple `gamewindow`, but now, don't know why, I can't anymore.

Here is what the console outputs:

```
Unhandled exception : System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for 'OpenTK.DisplayDevice'.
    ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for 'OpenTK.Platform.Factory'.
    ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Could not find entry point 'SDL_GameControllerEventState' in the DLL 'SDL2.dll'.

at OpenTK.Platform.SDL2.SDL.GameControllerEventState(EventState state)
at OpenTK.Platform.SDL2.Sdl2InputDriver..ctor() in c:\temp\opentk\Source\OpenTK\Platform\SDL2\Sdl2InputDriver.cs:line 58
at OpenTK.Platform.SDL2.Sdl2Factory..ctor() in c:\temp\opentk\Source\OpenTK\Platform\SDL2\Sdl2Factory.cs:line 37
at OpenTK.Platform.Factory..ctor() in c:\temp\opentk\Source\OpenTK\Platform\Factory.cs:line 60
at OpenTK.Toolkit.Init(ToolkitOptions options) in c:\temp\opentk\Source\OpenTK\Toolkit.cs:line 141
at OpenTK.Toolkit.Init() in c:\temp\opentk\Source\OpenTK\Toolkit.cs:line 91
at OpenTK.Platform.Factory..cctor() in c:\temp\opentk\Source\OpenTK\Platform\Factory.cs:line 51
--- End of internal exception stack trace ---
at OpenTK.Platform.Factory.get_Default()
at OpenTK.DisplayDevice..cctor() in c:\temp\opentk\Source\OpenTK\DisplayDevice.cs:line 68
--- End of internal exception stack trace ---
at OpenTK.DisplayDevice.get_Default()
at OpenTK.GameWindow..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, GraphicsMode mode, String title) in c:\temp\opentk\Source\OpenTK\GameWindow.cs:line 148
at ConsoleApplication1.StarterKit.Game..ctor() in C:\Users\Octogon\OctogonEngine\tests\test6\roslyn\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 22
at ConsoleApplication1.StarterKit.Game.Main() in C:\Users\Octogon\OctogonEngine\tests\test6\roslyn\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 81
```

`OpenTK.dll` is correctly referenced.

The `gamewindow` I am trying to launch is the `opentk` sample:
http://www.opentk.com/doc/chapter/0

Answer (score 1):

Here what solved the issue : https://github.com/opentk/opentk/issues/266

do that at launch if using opentk on windows

```
var options = new ToolkitOptions();
options.Backend = PlatformBackend.PreferNative;
Toolkit.Init(options);
```